# Trying to delete a row based upon condition defined in my trigger (SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-trigger

I am trying to create a row level trigger to delete a row if a value in the row is being made NULL. My business parameters state that if a value is being made null, then the row must be deleted. Also, I cannot use a global variable.

```sql
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.EXHIBIT_ID IS NULL THEN
   DELETE SHOWING
   WHERE EXHIBIT_ID = :OLD.EXHIBIT_ID;
  END IF;
```

I get the following errors:

```
ORA-04091: table ISA722.SHOWING is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
ORA-06512: at "ISA722.TRG_EXPAINT", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ISA722.TRG_EXPAINT'
```

When executing this query:

```sql
UPDATE SHOWING
  SET EXHIBIT_ID = NULL
WHERE PAINT_ID = 5104
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question using the `edit` button just below the tags and include the complete code to your trigger. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mutating error on after insert trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474674/mutating-error-on-after-insert-trigger)

Comment: You cannot alter a row in the same table that the trigger is on.  If the field should not be null, either add a NOT NULL constraint on the column, or raise an exception and let the caller figure out how to deal with it. This is not a good design otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

As already indicated this is a terrible idea/design. Triggers are very poor methods for enforcing business rules. These should be enforced in the application or better (IMO) by a stored procedure called by the application. In this case not only is it a bad idea, but it cannot be implemented as desired.  Within a trigger Oracle does not permit accessing the table the trigger fired was fired on. That is what mutating indicates. Think of trying to debug this or resolve a problem a week later. Nevertheless this non-sense can be accomplished by creating view and processing against it instead of the table.

```
-- setup 
create table showing (exhibit_id integer, exhibit_name varchar2(50));
create view show as select * from showing;
-- trigger on VIEW
create or replace trigger show_iiur
    instead of insert or update on show 
    for each row 
begin 
    merge into showing 
         using (select :new.exhibit_id new_eid
                     , :old.exhibit_id old_eid 
                     , :new.exhibit_name new_ename
                  from dual
               ) on (exhibit_id = old_eid)
         when matched then 
              update set exhibit_name = new_ename
              delete where new_eid is null
         when not matched then
              insert (exhibit_id, exhibit_name)
              values (:new.exhibit_id, :new.exhibit_name);
end ;
-- test data
 insert into show(exhibit_id, exhibit_name)
   select 1,'abc' from dual union all 
   select 2,'def' from dual union all
   select 3,'ghi' from dual; 
-- 3 rows inserted

select * from show;

--- test 
update show 
   set exhibit_name = 'XyZ'
 where exhibit_id = 3;
-- 1 row updated

-- Now for the requested action. Turn the UPDATE into a DELETE
 update show
    set exhibit_id = null 
  where exhibit_name = 'def'; 
-- 1 row updated

select * from show;

-- table and view are the same (expect o rows)
select * from show MINUS select * from showing
UNION ALL
select * from showing MINUS select * from show;
```

Again this is a bad option yet you can do. But just because you can doesn't mean you should. Or that you'll be happy with the result. Good Luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have written a trigger that fires after or before a row change. This is in the middle of an execution. You cannot delete a row from the same table in that moment.

So you must write an after statement trigger instead that only fires when the whole statement has run.

```
create or replace trigger mytrigger
after update of exhibit_id on showing 
begin
  delete from showing where exhibit_id is null;
end mytrigger;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=dd5ade700d49daf14f4cdc71aed48e17

Comment: I agree with the answer. But you can not reference any value in after statement trigger, which is actually a requirement of @DJones2525 -- [Demo of error](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2f00bd34e1d40753515c1fc6e729dcec)
-- Actually, Compound Triggers is a perfect solution. refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474674/mutating-error-on-after-insert-trigger) for solution.

Comment: Correct, a compund trigger would guarantee to only delete rows that were updated in the statement. I surmised that the table is not supposed to contain any rows where exhibit_id is null. In that case my simple trigger would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is create an extra column like is_to_be_deleted in the same table, and do this:

`UPDATE SHOWING
  SET EXHIBIT_ID = NULL, is_to_be_deleted = 'Y'
WHERE PAINT_ID = 5104;`

You can use this parameter to implement your business logic of not showing the null details.

And later you can schedule a batch delete on that table to clean up these rows (or maybe archive it). 
Benefit: you can avoid an extra unnecessary trigger on that table.

Nobody, will suggest you to use trigger to do this type of delete as it is expensive.